# Data acquisition/logging question

Tags: datalogging

I want to use an Arduino Uno for a data-acquisition purpose.

Normally adhoc data acquisition boards can record each sample at a desired sampling rate. So that I can plot all the samples recorded. I want to do the same sort if thing with Arduino.

I want to record 30 minutes of analog voltage input at 4kHz sampling rate and record all the samples taken to a PC.

And at the end I want to be able to plot the data with all samples not the averages ect.

Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: Depending on your data format that could be up to 28MB of data. No way an Arduino alone can deal with that without somewhere to off-load the storage to, such as maybe an SD card (that is if the Arduino can store data on SD that fast). 4kHz is a reasonable sampling speed for the Arduino, though you can't really use `analogRead()` for that. Instead you want to investigate free-running and/or timer based sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program I wrote that follows an approach somewhat similar to
Michael Stachowsky's answer:

- The ADC is configured with the prescaler set to 128 (just like the
  Arduino core does), which gives a 104 µs conversion time,
  significantly shorter than the 250 µs sampling period you want.
  The first conversion takes longer, and it is discarded.
- It is also configured an auto-trigger mode, and the timer 1 overflow
  flag is selected as its trigger source.
- The timer 1 is configured to loop every 500 × 8 = 4000 CPU cycles
  (clocked at F_CPU / 8, with TOP = 499), which
  provides the required 250 µs sampling period. It is set in a PWM
  mode even though the PWM outputs are not used, simply because in this
  mode the overflow flag is set every time the timer loops.
- An interrupt is triggered every time an ADC conversion is complete.
  The interrupt service routine clears the timer overflow flag (this is
  required because the ADC is triggered by the rising edges of this
  flag), saves the result in a global variable and sets a global flag.
- The main loop waits for that flag and sends the data through the
  serial port, in binary, LSB first:

  - the sample number modulo 64 (6 bits)
  - the sample value (10 bits).
- The serial port runs at 115.2 kb/s, it can then transmit the two bytes
  of data in about 174 µs, which is less than the sampling period.
- The sample numbers, and a 16-byte preamble can be used as a sanity
  check by the receiving end.

```c++
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Transmit preamble.
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        Serial.write(0xff);

    // Start the ADC.
    ADMUX  = _BV(REFS0)   // reference = Vcc
           | 0;           // input = ADC0
    ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)    // enable the ADC
           | _BV(ADSC)    // start first conversion
           | _BV(ADPS0)   // prescaler = 128,
           | _BV(ADPS1)   // ditto
           | _BV(ADPS2);  // ditto

    // Wait for the first conversion to complete.
    loop_until_bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADIF);

    // Wait for the preamble to be fully transmitted.
    Serial.flush();

    // Stop timer 1.
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;

    // Configure the ADC in auto-trigger mode.
    ADCSRA |= _BV(ADATE)   // enable auto-trigger
            | _BV(ADIF)    // clear interrupt flag
            | _BV(ADIE);   // enable interrupt
    ADCSRB  = _BV(ADTS1)   // trigger source = timer 1 overflow
            | _BV(ADTS2);  // ditto

    // Configure Timer 1.
    ICR1   = 500 - 1;     // period = 500 * 8 CPU cycles
    TCCR1A = _BV(WGM11);  // mode 14: fast PWM,
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)   // ... TOP = ICR1,
           | _BV(WGM13)   // ... overflow flag set on TOP
           | _BV(CS11);   // clock at F_CPU / 8
}

volatile uint16_t reading = 0xffff;
volatile bool reading_available;

ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    TIFR1 |= _BV(TOV1);    // clear timer overflow flag
    uint16_t x = reading;  // work on a copy of the reading
    x &= ~0x03ff;          // remove previous ADC value
    x |= ADC;              // add current ADC value
    x += 0x0400;           // increment sample number
    reading = x;
    reading_available = true;
}

void loop()
{
    // Wait for a reading to be available.
    while (!reading_available) ;

    // Grab a copy.
    uint16_t x = reading;
    reading_available = false;

    // Transmit, LSB first.
    Serial.write(x >> 0);  // low byte
    Serial.write(x >> 8);  // high byte
}
```

How you deal with the data on the receiving end (save to file, skip
preamble, check sample number consistency, extract sample values, plot
them...) is up to you. You can use whatever language and tools you want.
It is *not* an Arduino-related question.

**Addendum**: More about the binary format used.

There is a preamble consisting of 16 `0xff` bytes. This can be useful
because it is not uncommon to get in one file a mix of data from two
different runs of the program. The buffering of the serial port on the
PC can lead to this happening. If you do not want that preamble, remove
the two lines right after the “Transmit preamble.” comment.

Then there is a continuous stream of 16-bit unsigned integers
(`uint16_t`), transmitted LSB first (i.e. little endian). The byte order
can be changed by swapping the two `Serial.write()` by the end of the
program.

Each of these integers contains an ADC reading in the lower 10 bits and
a sample number in the upper 6 bits. The sample number can be extracted
by right-shifting (`x >> 10` in C) and could be used as a sanity check
(the number should increment by 1, modulo 64, from one sample to the
next). The ADC reading can be extracted by masking out the sample number
(`x & 0x03ff`).

If you do not want the sample numbers, you can simplify the ISR to:

```c++
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    TIFR1 |= _BV(TOV1);    // clear timer overflow flag
    reading = ADC;         // read the ADC result
    reading_available = true;
}
```

and remove the (now useless) initialization of the `reading` variable.

Comment: Thanks I uploaded the code. In Arduino IDE's serial monitor I'm see weird characters not ones and zeros or numbers. How can I convert the upcoming data to numbers? And which analog input is this code sampling?

Comment: @user16307: It's sampling analog input 0. You can sample another input by replacing the `0` in the line `| 0;  // input = ADC0`. You see weird characters because it's binary data, not text. If you want text, you will have to convert it. How you do the conversion is up to you, and **it's not an Arduino question**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I would be glad at least of you tell me which binary format is this code sending data? If I save the data and when I convert the binary to text I need to know the format saved. Is it uint16? Im not so familiar with. MATLAB has functions to read such binary. I mean is this data uint16 little endian?

Comment: @user16307: Yes, it's uint16 little endian. I amended the answer to make the format more explicit, and to provide instructions on how you can change it.

Comment: Im still trying to extract the time and voltage readings from your code. Is 8 bit part is time in seconds and the other 8 bit part is voltage reading? Why dont you use Serial.print instead of Serial.write?

Comment: @user16307: No, it's 6 bits: sample number and 10 bits: voltage reading. `Serial.print()` would format the result in ASCII, which would be easier to deal with on the receiving end, but it takes more bytes to send. At 4 K samples/second, there is no time to send ASCII-formatted readings through Serial. Binary is your only option.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thanks. So what I need to do is to divide the 16 bit to two parts 6 bit and 10 bit in C# part. I still couldn't manage it. Maybe I should only use the voltage readings. In that case I will update the ISR(ADC_vect) as you mentioned in addendum. In that case the line Serial.write(x >> 0);  // low byte will send the voltage readings right?

Comment: I think I was wrong.   Both Serial.write(x >> 0);  // low byte
    Serial.write(x >> 8);  // high byte should be used to transmit 10 bit data. Now I only receive voltage data by setting ISR(ADC_vect) to ur suggestion. I use Realterm terminal program and get values of tens of thousands as voltage readings as uint16. Shouldnt the uint16(eventhough it can up to around 65000) format output max 255 since max ADC is 10 bit? Did you try this code before? Please test your code with Realterm if u have time. I dont understand why Im having that big numbers.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake again the baud rates were not matching before. now it works 5V corresponds 1024. is that ICR1   = 500 - 1;  line setting sampling  rate? is it possible to sample 1Hz modifying this code? thanks anyway..

Comment: @user16307: In order to get a 1 Hz sampling, you have to set the prescaler to 256 (replace `CS11` by `CS12` in the code), and set `ICR1 = 62500 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually two or three different questions.

To the first: is it possible to record 30 minutes of data with an arduino uno at 4KHz: no.  Assuming even that you are only taking 1 byte of data at a time, the uno only has 2K of RAM, so you'd be out of RAM in under a second.

To the second: can you instead send this data to a PC at the desired rate: possibly, depending on how much data you are taking.  If it's just a single analog channel, then you can most likely do it.  Anything more and I doubt it.  The problem is that you'll simulutaneously have to read the analog at the correct time AND send the data to the PC, presumably over the serial.  As long as you use Serial.write, NOT Serial.print, then your UART should be more than fast enough at high baud rates to handle a single channel with minimal overhead.  However, that would mean that you have to reconstruct the data on the PC, but that's the third question, to which I shall turn shortly.

If you need absolute real-time operation, then you need to use timer interrupts, which are not native to the Arduino libraries, if I recall correctly.  However, a quick google for "Arduino timer interrupt" leads me here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1, which is where you should start.

In terms of plotting the data: that's not an Arduino problem, that's a problem for whatever you choose to use to collect and analyze your data.  I suggest Excel, since it's relatively common, or Google Sheets, since it's free.  If you have access to Matlab, though, that's a much more powerful program.  Either way, that is off topic for this forum.

Comment: Rather than a timer interrupt, I would use a timer to trigger the ADC, and the ADC interrupt to read the data. This will provide a more steady acquisition rate than triggering the ADC from a timer ISR.